# How to pinpoint what process uses the disk using NMON on AIX

Tags: performance, aix

On an AIX 7.2 machine I need to investigate what is causing daily slowdowns between certain hours, and after analyzing the .nmon files using the `nmon` analyzer excel I've found that indeed the Disk Busy Graphic show that at least one of my hard drives reaches 100% utilization for about 45 minutes.

This is the `nmon` command I am using:

```
nmon -f -T -s 10 -c 720 -d -V -P -m /my/nmon/location/
```

What I would really like to do is to pinpoint the exact process(es) that are using the disk(s) during that period.  I thought that searching for any processes that run at the same time the disk usage spikes occur would reveal the cause.

So let's assume that I see the disk usage graphic spike at 15.00, should I just go to the UARG tab and search for whatever process is running around that time? Is it correct to assume that the most CPU consuming process is to blame for the disk usage?

Please note that I have no running jobs during that time.

Comment: No, assuming that the process consuming the most CPU is to blame for the disk usage would not be correct.  It’s probably safe to assume that *one* (or more) of the processes running at that time are responsible.  If there are some processes that run only at that time, then obviously they are a good place to start looking.  But it’s always possible that some background process that just hangs out 24×7 wakes up and does something special once a day. I won’t be able to help you beyond this; I haven’t used AIX in many years, and I’m not familiar with ```nmon```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a 10-second interval between snapshots and the `-T` option, you're capturing the top processes every 10 seconds; hopefully the offending process is using enough CPU time to be considered a "top" process in one of those timeframes.

Once you have the timeframe, I would grep for that "snapshot number" from the NMON file and sort the results by the CHARIO column. That would give you a good indication as to which process(es) had the most I/O assigned to them.

Get the snapshot number with:

```
grep ^ZZZZ,T /my/nmon/location/my-file.nmon
```

You'll get results back that look like:

```
ZZZZ,T0001,11:43:21,26-SEP-2018
ZZZZ,T0002,11:43:31,26-SEP-2018
ZZZZ,T0003,11:43:41,26-SEP-2018
```

Find the T000 numbers corresponding to the 15:00 timeframe, then grep for those T codes from the nmon file and sort by column 11 (CHARIO); for example:

```
grep '^TOP,.*,T0024' my-file.nmon | sort -t, -k11n
```

The entries at the bottom of each timeframe performed the most I/O in that timeframe. If you see the same process for that 45-minute duration in question, you have a good candidate. Of course, that process could be innocent of *your* I/O -- it could be performing terminal I/O or I/O to other disks.